# Can't save data with mongoose, facing schema issue

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I suspect it's because of my schema, my callback returned this

```
{ artists: {}, albums: [], _id: 56f389fdaf77ed1021b8f504, __v: 0 }
```

but when I check my db the document wasn't there.

This is how my schema look like

```
var LyricSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    artists:
   { id: String,
     name: String,
     images: String
},
  albums:
   [ { album: [{
    id:String,
    name:String,
    image:String
   }], 
   tracks: [{
    name:String
   }] }]
});
```

and this is what I sent to use create method to save the data into the db.
http://pastebin.com/svGVYab2

Comment: Please try to change `albums` as ` albums:[{ 
    album: {
  id:String,
  name:String,
  image:String
 }, 
   tracks: {name: [String]}
  }]`

Comment: @zangw I got this ` { "_id": { "$oid": "56f38f51f60ccfac277f69ff" }, "albums": [], "__v": 0 }` inserted in my db.

Comment: Please add yours insert data codes to your question...

Comment: @zangw http://pastebin.com/UWZUCY3r

Comment: I did not find where the `save` function is called? and the parameter `json` passed into this function.

Comment: @zangw http://pastebin.com/Z1PdmtAC

Comment: What the output of `console.log(req.body.data)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think album should be an object not an array, and the tracks is wrong too, check this:

```
var LyricSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  artists: {
    id: String,
    name: String,
    images: String
  },
  albums: [{
    album: {
      id: String,
      name: String,
      image: String
    },
    tracks: {
      name: Array
    }
  }]
});
```

Comment: I got this in my db.` {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56f38f51f60ccfac277f69ff"
    },
    "albums": [],
    "__v": 0
}`

Comment: Try to insert only a single record.

Comment: single record means?